# django filter - how to get filtered objects

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have a model named `Container` which has the fields `received` and `name`. I'm using [`django-filter`](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to filter on those fields. 
After filtering I get the result:

```
<list.filters.AdvancedSearchListFilter object at 0x7f68cd698828>
```

Here is my `filter` class:

```
class AdvancedSearchListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    field-1 = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(label='Received Date Range')

    class Meta:
        model = Container
        fields = ['field-1', 'field-2']
```

How do I get the filtered results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an object of your `filter` class like this:

```
filter = FilterClass(query)
```

Where `query` is type `dict`, for example - to get all files named `file.txt`, set `query` to `{'name': 'file.txt'}`.
You can also specify the `queryset` argument, but if it's not provided then all the items in the default manager of the model will be used, in your case `queryset = Container.objects.all()`.

To get the filtered results, access `filter.qs` or iterate over `filter`:

```
{% for obj in filter %}
    {{ obj.field-2 }} - ${{ obj.field-1 }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Also, you didn't specify a [`lookup_type`](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=lookup_type#custom-lookup-types), by default it is **the exact term**. Add `lookup_type` to your `filter` class like this:

- To search on part of the text:
  `field-1 = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_type='icontains')`
  To get all entries with `foo` in field-1, set `query` to  `{'field-1': 'foo'}`
- To search on dates earlier than:
  `field-2 = django_filters.DateFilter(lookup_type='lt')`
  To get all entries received before today, set `query` to  `{'field-2': datetime.date.today()}`

In case you would like to search on a date in `range`:
`field-1 = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter()`
 To get all entries received in a date range, set `query` to  `{'received_0': start_date, 'field-1_1': end_date}`

There are more examples in the formal documentation [`django-filter`](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: @SnehaShinde if you want to get the results from the filter object you need to access the the `qs` property. Have a look at my answer which I posted yesterday.

Comment: @AKS: I have tried :                                                        advanced_filters = AdvancedSearchInboxFilter('2016-03-02',  queryset=File.objects.all())                                                                        It returns : advanced_filters : <inbox.filters.AdvancedSearchInboxFilter object at 0x7f3409850278>.   then file_objs=advanced_filters.qs  it gives me an error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @SnehaShinde please read my response again, it doesn't look like you understood it fully. You should initiate your filter class like this `AdvancedSearchInboxFilter({'received_0': start_date, 'received_1': end_date})`.

Comment: @Forge: yes...now I am able to get the list of of filtered objects.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [documentation](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#the-view) you can access the queryset using `f.qs` where f is your filter object.

> If you want to access the filtered objects in your views, for example if you want to paginate them, you can do that. They are in `f.qs`.

So if you are getting the results from the filter as following:

```
result = AdvancedSearchListFilter(query, queryset=queryset)
```

Note, that this `query` needs to be a `dict` and not a `string`:

```
# 2016-03-02
query = {'received': datetime.date(2016, 3, 2)} # or your own custom date
```

You can access the `Container` objects from the result using `qs` property:

```
container_objs = result.qs
```

---

I also looked at the implementation of [`DjangoFilterBackend`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/filters.py#L115) in `django-rest-framework` and there also they use `qs` to access the objects:

```
    if filter_class:
        return filter_class(request.query_params, queryset=queryset).qs
```

Comment: file_objs = result.qs gives me an error like:AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
Note:I am using python 3.4 and Django 1.9 version.

Comment: Can you show how are you creating the object of `AdvancedSearchInboxFilter`?

Comment: Look at the update answer. You are passing `string` in query but it should be a `dict`.

Comment: ohh yes got it...Thank you so much.

Comment: @SnehaShinde: The changes you have made are trivial (just the name of the objects or the class) from the conceptual point of view. You did it both in the question and in the answer. If anyone read the previous question and answer they would have the same understanding as now. While I have approved your edit, I don't think this is a practice which will be welcomed in the community.

Comment: In the end, it doesn't matter if it is a File or a Container or what is the name of the filter etc. What really matters is that you know how you can access the queryset in this particular scenario.